# Tour through coordinates with smallest/ most efficient path (Scipy distance.cdist) 3D?

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter-notebook, ipython, distance

I have code written in IPython using Jupyter Notebook that finds all the black pixels of an image and finds the shortest path between them.

I would like to something similar in 3D.
Using point clouds, i have the coordinates of points that define an object in 3D space. How can i find the shortest/most logical path between these to draw them/connect the dots in one line.

Is it possible to adapt the 2D code (removing anything to do with pixels, and just inputing x,y,z coords?)

> The Goal: Input 3D coordinates, find the most logical/least messy path connecting them all, using this new path, reorder the coordinates from start --> end of the path, output these organized coordinates.

Here is my current 2D code:

```
class ImageObject:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        response = requests.get(url)
        self.img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        self.og_size = self.img.size

    def show(self):
        imshow(np.asarray(self.img))

    def monochrome(self, scale=3, threshold=200):

        # convert image to monochrome
        image = self.img.convert('L')
        image_array = np.array(image)

        # Binarize a numpy array using threshold as cutoff
        for i in range(len(image_array)):
            for j in range(len(image_array[0])):
                if image_array[i][j] > threshold:
                    image_array[i][j] = 255
                else:
                    image_array[i][j] = 0

        image = Image.fromarray(image_array)

        # scale image down to reduce number of non-zero pixels
        img_sm = image.resize(tuple([int(v/scale) for v in image.size]),Image.ANTIALIAS)

        # convert image to black and white
        img_bw = img_sm.convert(mode='1', dither=2) 
        self.bw_img = img_bw
        self.pixels = (1 - np.asarray(img_bw).astype(int))
        self.pixels_flat = np.reshape(self.pixels, self.pixels.size)

    def show_bw(self):
        print("Dimensions: {}".format(self.bw_img.size))
        print("Num. pixels: {}".format(self.pixels.sum()))
        imshow(np.asarray(self.bw_img))

    def get_tour(self, starting_point="random", plot=True):
        # Get greedy tour through pixels

        absolute_index = np.where(self.pixels_flat > 0)[0] # positions of non-zero pixels
        relative_index = np.array(range(1, len(absolute_index)+1 ))

        # Replace each non-zero pixel in the array with its number
        # i.e., the 10th non-zero pixel will have 10 in its place
        flat_img_mod = deepcopy(self.pixels_flat)
        for rel, pix in enumerate(absolute_index):
            flat_img_mod[pix] = rel+1

        # Get coordiantes for each non-zero pixel
        img_idx = np.reshape(flat_img_mod, self.pixels.shape)
        self.coord_list = []
        for p1 in relative_index:
            p1_coords = tuple([int(c) for c in np.where(img_idx==p1)])
            self.coord_list.append(list(p1_coords))

        # Calcualte distance between each pair of coords
        dist_mat = distance.cdist(self.coord_list, self.coord_list, 'euclidean')

        # Initialize search space with nearest neighbor tour
        cities = self.coord_list
        num_cities = len(cities)
        if starting_point=="random":
            start = int(np.random.choice(range(num_cities),size=1))
        else:
            assert starting_point < num_cities
            start = starting_point
        tour = [start]
        active_city = start
        for step in range(0, num_cities):
            dist_row = deepcopy(dist_mat[active_city,:])
            for done in tour:
                dist_row[done] = np.inf
            nearest_neighbor = np.argmin(dist_row)
            if nearest_neighbor not in tour:
                tour.append(nearest_neighbor)
            active_city = nearest_neighbor

        y_tour = -np.array([cities[tour[i % num_cities]] for i in range(num_cities+1) ])[:,0]
        y_tour = y_tour - y_tour[0]#- min(y_tour)
        x_tour = np.array([cities[tour[i % num_cities]] for i in range(num_cities+1) ])[:,1]    
        x_tour = x_tour - x_tour[0]#- min(x_tour)

        # Circle tour back to beginning
        np.append(x_tour, x_tour[0])
        np.append(y_tour, y_tour[0])
        num_cities = num_cities + 1

        self.x_tour = x_tour
        self.y_tour = y_tour
        self.num_pixels = num_cities

        if plot:
            plt.plot(self.x_tour, self.y_tour)

    def get_splines(self, degree=5, plot=True):
        # Convert tours into parametric spline curves

        x_spl = UnivariateSpline(list(range(0,self.num_pixels)), self.x_tour, k=degree)
        y_spl = UnivariateSpline(list(range(0,self.num_pixels)), self.y_tour, k=degree)

        self.x_spl = x_spl
        self.y_spl = y_spl

        if plot:
            p = plt.plot(*zip(*[(x_spl(v), y_spl(v)) for v in np.linspace(0, self.num_pixels-1, 1000)]))


    def plot_parametric(self, num_points=1000):
        # num_points = number of points at which to sample the curves
        t_vals, x_vals = zip(*[
            (v, self.x_spl(v)) for v in np.linspace(0, self.num_pixels, num_points)
        ])
        x_vals = np.array(x_vals)
        y_vals = np.array([self.y_spl(v) for v in np.linspace(0, self.num_pixels, num_points)])
        t_vals = np.array(t_vals)

        plt.plot(t_vals, x_vals)
        plt.plot(t_vals, y_vals)
```

Comment: Look up traveling salesman problem. I can't help but feel that it's related.

Comment: wow! this seems exactly what im looking for. Any idea how to implement it. do you know of any current algorithms? I'm excited now! :D

Comment: There's no reasonable complete solution, only heuristics.

Comment: I actually found a tool, and it works great using mathematica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mathematica's `FindShortestTour` Function

```
Find the length and ordering of the shortest tour through points in the plane:

In[1]:= 
 Click for copyable input
✕
pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 
5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 
1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}};
Copy to clipboard.
In[2]:= 
 Click for copyable input
✕
pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 
5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 
1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}};
FindShortestTour[%]
Copy to clipboard.
Out[2]= 

Order the points according to the tour found:

In[3]:= 
 Click for copyable input
✕
pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 
5}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 
1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}};
FindShortestTour[%];
pts[[Last[%]]]
Copy to clipboard.
Out[3]= 

Plot the tour:

In[4]:= 
 Click for copyable input
Copy to clipboard.
Out[4]=
```